# How to name properly a question containing two options?

Tags: word-request

Can I call a question like

> Do you want a red or blue eraser?

an '*alternative question*' or should I call it a '*question with two alternatives*'?

Answer (score 3):

You can call them *binary questions*.

> **binary** *adjective*
>   Relating to, composed of, or involving two things.
>   ‘To avoid the binary thinking that collapses complexity, it is necessary to assess both similarities and differences while watchful for the excesses of either prejudice.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/binary)

Here are some usage examples:

- A binary question is one with two possible answers, such as yes or no, or equivalently, true or false, or even one or zero.
  [- Quantum Structural Studies](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=E8SkDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA166&dq=%22binary%20question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinx6HyoZjXAhWIgrwKHX1iBVwQ6AEILjAB)
- Use Binary and Non-Binary Questions When Selling
  [- Michael Angelo Caruso](https://michaelangelocaruso.com/use-binary-and-non-binary-questions-when-selling/)
- What is a binary question? It is a question that only requires only two possible answers. (Example:Yes or No)
  [- answers.com](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_binary_question)

Regarding whether such questions may be called *alternative questions* or *questions with two alternatives*: the latter is fine, but the natural reading of the term *alternative question* is another question that one might answer instead of the 'primary' question. For example, in a guessing game that has a question that is difficult to answer, you might have an *alternative question* that is easier to answer but gives you fewer points.

Comment: But is '_Binary Question_' the best option? I've never come across this being used, in day-to-day conversations.

Comment: @VarunNair I think so :) . But you don't have to take my word for it. Have a look at the usage examples I provided.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong. It's actually a very good alternative. But I'm not sure it's that commonly used, that's all

Comment: @VarunNair I suppose *multiple-choice questions* are more common in tests, but *binary questions* have a respectable representation in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=binary+question%2Cmultiple+choice+question%2Cquestion+with+two+alternatives&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbinary%20question%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmultiple%20choice%20question%3B%2Cc0), where "question with two alternatives" doesn't even get a mention.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to pick one from the two you provided, I'd go with '**[alternate question](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/questions-alternative-questions-is-it-black-or-grey)**'. The second one, is however very tricky and can be ambiguous.

If you tell me *'a question with two alternatives'*, I can either interpret it as:

> a question with two solutions or options.

or

> a question, with two alternative questions.

You could even try *[multiple-choice question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_choice#Structure)*, but then again, that's a question with more than one solution, and can have two, three or any number of choices.

Or you could simply call it '*a question with two choices*'.